# How to tell current internship that I've signed elsewhere after graduation?

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-offer, ethics, internship

First post here so bear with me if I forget some rules.

Background: I'm a senior in college remotely interning part-time at Company A. The internship offer letter from Company A said that it's set to end in February but I do have the option to continue working through spring semester as well. During fall semester, my school had career fairs, in-person interview nights, and many events where other companies came in and talked to students at my school. I interviewed at several places (while also interning at A) and received an offer from Company B. I signed this offer since I enjoyed Company B's values and type of work much more than Company A. I know company A has already said they aim to turn interns into full-time employees after graduation; but, I was never interested in working for them full-time. I just want money during the school year + I don't see myself working here in the future.

Do I tell company A that I've made this choice or do I just keep quiet so that I can work through spring semester with no issues? I have a talk coming up soon with my boss about my future (everyone has a check-in, so not just me) so I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: I worked as a contractor for a very large company [you would most likely recognize the name] and they treated interns MUCH better than contractors.  They wanted to have the interns work for them eventually.  They had a good-bye party for an intern; I also was leaving, but they only included me as a sort-of-afterthought!  See also my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to tell Company A yet that you will not be working for them after the spring *unless* they directly ask. If they do ask, since you're an intern, not a full-time employee, it shouldn't be an issue to tell them you already have an offer lined up somewhere else.

An internship offers both the company and the intern the chance to see how well they fit together. One or the other deciding it isn't a good fit is normal. In my experience, it's fine to be honest with the company about not moving to full time employment as an intern. They expect interns to be looking elsewhere, too. Letting them know now, if they ask, will let them plan what they want you to work on better. It should not bring about negative repercussions.

Comment: My answer is somewhat similar, it was published just seconds after this answer, so it is not plagarism.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Would you advise me asking my boss directly if she has plans for me after graduation during our upcoming chat?

Comment: @studentatsomewhere if you're not planning to stay, then no.

Answer (score 2):

I'd wait as long as possible.

If your internship automatically ends with the semester, you may not need to inform them at all.

If your work is expected to continue, I'd give two weeks' notice as with any job.

This is for U.S. expectations; exact timing of notice may depend on location and culture.

Also:  You may find the other job is much worse than expected and you want to return to the place you are leaving, so try not to burn bridges.

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other job, you don't have to tell them until you have to.

> received an offer from Company B. I signed this offer since I enjoyed
> Company B's values and type of work much more than Company A.

I assume that other then graduation there are no other contingencies with company B. I assume that they have completed all the background checks, criminal checks, and drug checks. If they haven't then you still don't have a guaranteed job.

You goal for company A is to keep your current position until just before the job in Company B starts.

Expect that company A will want to discuss the spring semester, and a full-time position. You don't want to commit to company A, but you also don't want them to stop considering you until you have to tell them.

Yes they know that interns are always looking for jobs. They also sometimes think that interns always want to stay. That isn't your concern.  Telling them too soon could cut your current position. They are willing to let interns be inefficient because they want you to pick them. Once you have said no, they have little reason to keep you around.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful! Do you have any advice on what I should say if my boss asks what my plans are after graduation/ brings up future plans? Do I hide the offer or do I just evade and say "i don't know"?